# Meaning of partial correlation

Tags: correlation, partial-correlation, conditioning

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation)

> Formally, the partial correlation between $X$ and $Y$ given a set of $n$ controlling variables $Z = \{Z_1, Z_2, …, Z_n\}$, written $ρ_{XY·Z}$, is the correlation between the residuals $RX$ and $RY$ resulting from the linear regression of $X$ with $Z$ and of $Y$ with $Z$, respectively.

1. It says earlier that

   > partial correlation measures the degree of association between two random variables, with the effect of a set of controlling random
   >   variables removed.

   I was wondering how the partial correlation $ρ_{XY·Z}$ is related to
   the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ conditional on $Z$?
2. There is a special case for $n=1$.

   > In fact, the first-order partial correlation (i.e. when $n=1$) is nothing else than a difference between a correlation and the product
   >   of the removable correlations divided by the product of the
   >   coefficients of alienation of the removable correlations. The
   >   coefficient of alienation, and its relation with joint variance
   >   through correlation are available in Guilford (1973, pp. 344–345).

   I was wondering how to write the above down mathematically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that correlation conditional on $Z$ is a variable that depends on $Z$, whereas partial correlation is a single number.

Furthermore, partial correlation is defined based on the residuals from linear regression. Thus, if the actual relationship is nonlinear, the partial correlation may obtain a different value than the conditional correlation, even if the correlation conditional on $Z$ is a constant independent of $Z$. On the other hand, if $X, Y, Z$ are multivariate Gaussian, the partial correlation equals the conditional correlation.

For an example where constant conditional correlation $\neq$ partial correlation: $$Z\sim U(-1,1),~X=Z^2+e,~Y=Z^2-e,~e\sim N(0,1),e\perp Z.$$ No matter which value $Z$ takes, the conditional correlation will be -1. However, the linear regressions $X|Z$,$Y|Z$ will be constants 0, and thus the residuals will be the values $X$,$Y$ themselves. Thus, the partial correlation equals the correlation between $X$,$Y$; which does not equal -1, as clearly the variables are not perfectly correlated if $Z$ is not known.

Apparently, [Baba and Sibuya (2005)](http://www.scipress.org/journals/jjss/pdf/3501/35010001.pdf) show the equivalence of partial correlation and conditional correlation for some other distributions besides multivariate Gaussian, but I did not read this.

The answer to your question 2 seems to exist in the Wikipedia article, the second equation under [Using recursive formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Using_recursive_formula).